ServeMux gets evaluated only once
I am seeing some unexpected behavior in my Go program and am hoping somebody can explain it to me.
I have the following basic program:
    package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    runserver()
}

func runserver() {
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":5000", mux())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func mux() *http.ServeMux {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()

    mux.HandleFunc("/p1", func1)
    mux.HandleFunc("/p2", func2)
    mux.HandleFunc("/p3", midd("hello", func3))

    return mux
}

func func1(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("called 1")
    w.Write([]byte("hello from 1"))
}

func func2(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("called 2")
    w.Write([]byte("hello from 2"))
}

func func3(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("called 3") 
    w.Write([]byte("hello from 3"))
}

func midd(random string, hfunc http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    fmt.Println(random)

    return hfunc
}

When I run the program, I immediately see hello (from func midd) printed in the terminal.
When I navigate to localhost:5000/p1, it prints "called 1", if I navigate to /p2 it prints "called 2" but when I navigate to /p3, I get "called 3" in the terminal but not hello.
Can anybody explain to my why midd() is called when the program starts but not when I navigate to "/p3"?

The statement mux.HandleFunc("/p3", midd("hello", func3)) executes the midd("hello", func3) call expression "then and there" and passes its result to the mux.HandleFunc function call. This result that's passed to HandleFunc is then invoked for each incoming /p3 request.
And the aforementioned statement is executed only once because mux() is called by runserver() only once, and runserver() is called by main() only once, and main() is executed only once.

Thank you for this explanation. This makes sense.

You are probably confused by higher-order functions.
mux.HandleFunc takes a function as the second argument, but does not execute it (immediately), it is only used when calling the registered URL. Also, when you call midd, it is executed immediately (printing its parameter random), but returns its function parameter hfunc as a value without executing the function. Perhaps this clears things up a little (Go Playground):
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    f := createFunction()

    fmt.Println("First")

    executeFunction(f)
}

func createFunction() func() {
    return func() {
        fmt.Println("Second")
    }
}

func executeFunction(f func()) {
    f()
}

